# не получается перетащить изображение в Adobe XD

Tags: adobe

Здравствуйте! Не получается перетащить или скопировать изображение в Adobe XD. Появляется знак запрета (кружок с перечеркнутой линией). Возможно, у кого-то была такая проблема. Подскажите, возможно что-то нужно изменить в настройках. Спасибо.

Comment: Добавьте больше описания, возможно скриншот, может быть еще что-то, что вы сочтете уместным добавить в вопрос. На данный момент сложно сказать, как решить вашу проблему

Comment: Уважаемый  Sergey Glazirin! Мне нужно вначале открыть фото в программе по умолчанию (Window 10, Photos), там скопировать, затем вставить в элемент (квадрат) в Adobe XD. Сейчас только так получается.